# How to conditionally use an HTML tag with JQuery

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have an application that uses bootstrap and JQuery. On the website page it displays some links. Based on a certain condition that I set in the JavaScript file, I want to strikethrough those links. On my HTML page, landing.html, I have this code for the links as follows:

```
<div class = "container">
<div class="row row-eq-height" style="border: none; height: 70px; padding:10px;"></div>
<h1>Surveys</h1>
<li><a target="_blank" href.bind="PreTestLink">PreTest Survey 1</a></li>
<li><a target="_blank" href.bind="PreTestLink2">PreTest Survey 2</a></li>
</div>
```

In my JavaScript file, landing.js, I have a constructor method with this field that I would like to use as the condition for setting the above links to be strikethrough-ed or not:

```
 import {RouterConfiguration, Router} from 'aurelia-router';
 var myApp;
 export class Landing {

 static inject() { return [Router]; }

 constructor(router){
    this.router = router;
    myApp = this;
    this.config = {}
    this.surveyCode1 = "";
    this.surveyCode2 = "";
    this.surveyCompleted = false;
 }
...
 if(some condition){
    this.surveyCompleted = true;
 }
```

Now, I know that with JQuery, I can send a value from the html file (i.e perhaps typed in by the user into a textbox) over to the JavaScript file by inserting:

```
 value.bind="username"
```

into the HTML tag. I also know that strikethrough in HTML can be done with a:

```
<del> tag
```

I'm just not sure how to connect this logic in reverse, to use my surveyCompleted conditional variable to set the  tag within my HTML page.

Comment: Where are you getting this  `this.surveyCompleted` as when you get the value you can accordingly handle the strikeout. Also if you can create a demo of your exact scenario, will be able to help better..

Comment: @Manish I updated my post to show when this.surveyCompleted is modified in my JS file, to handle the strikeout there would I need to do the strikeout in JS code versus in HTML code?

Comment: if you surveyCompleted true than dynamically add link into html page with strikethrough and without strikethrough accoeding to condition.

Comment: Yes @pal that's what I want to do, but how do I do that?

Comment: Are you using aurelia?

Comment: @Manish yes I was using Aurelia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code seems like its using Aurelia. So i would recommend you use aurelia and not Jquery for this. So this should be quite easy as Aurelia supports conditional templates.
[Official Docs](https://aurelia.io/docs/templating/basics#conditionals). So what you can do something like this.

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row row-eq-height" style="border: none; height: 70px; padding:10px;"></div>
  <h1>Surveys</h1>
  <li>
    <a target="_blank" if.bind="!surveyCompleted" href.bind="PreTestLink">PreTest Survey 1</a>
    <a if.bind="surveyCompleted" target="_blank" href.bind="PreTestLink"><del>PreTest Survey 1</del></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a target="_blank" if.bind="!surveyCompleted" href.bind="PreTestLink">PreTest Survey 2</a>
    <a if.bind="surveyCompleted" target="_blank" href.bind="PreTestLink"><del>PreTest Survey 2</del></a>
  </li>
```

I dont know aurelia but i think this must do the trick for you. Let me know if you still face issues.

Hope this helps :)